# Mysql - selecting a row with checksum value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm designing a small ecommerce website with a mysql database. I wanted to keep the URL clean without any hard coded product id.

So given a path http://example.com/shop/{product-name}

I opted to convert the {product-name} to a crc32 checksum in PHP and store it in the product table.

When a request is received for a product page, it is converted to crc32 checksum and queried for matching rows. I did this only for the product pages and blog pages.

My question

1. So far its working well on localhost. Will this be a scalable solution once traffic increases? Any way to test this?
2. Will indexing the checksum column help for Select queries?

   checksum INT UNIQUE NOT NULL

I read insert statement will take a performance hit. But assuming inserts would be occasional (2-3 per week for blog or new products once in 3 months perhaps) a 2-3 seconds time is acceptable. How bad could it get?

3. Is storing the checksum value as a binary better? Consider the additional task of converting the checksum to binary before every request.

Comment: Not sure about checksums, but for UUIDs it is definitely best practice to store them as binary in your database table.

Comment: Indexing your checksum column would definitely help if you're querying it often. I would not worry about inserts given the frequency you describe. As for scalability the answer is 'it depends'.

Comment: Im a big fan of http://hashids.org/ for this issue, or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/47820957/661872

Comment: Why bother with a checksum when you already have the product name field in the database? Just search for the product name.

Comment: What's the checksum supposed to be good for to begin with? Are you trying to match misspelled product names or something like that?

Comment: Unless you're operating at Amazon scale, the difference in lookup time (and other database resource use) for an indexed `varchar(255)` column and an indexed checksum column is trivial. It's **far far less costly** than the programming and maintenance hassle you'll incur.  Seriously. Unless you have well over a million distinct product names in your store, don't do this. Simple is smart.

Comment: ^^ Unless you want ugly/malformed product names, you would need to have a slug column, if you want decent SEO.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I initially was using select with url name (varchar) but after reading integers were faster to query i figured a checksum would be better. Paralysis by analysis i guess :p

Comment: @O.Jones so searching by url is far better for my case. Actually simplifies my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm designing a small ecommerce website with a mysql database. I wanted to keep the URL clean without any hard coded product id.
>
> So given a path http://example.com/shop/{product-name}

So, you mean `https://example.com/shop/jelly-donut` and `https://example.com/shop/coffee`, for example. Excellent. Good search engine optimization.

> I opted to convert the {product-name} to a crc32 checksum in PHP and store it in the product table.

This approach has several problems.

1. There are potential collisions in such a short checksum. More than one product could easily map to the same checksum. This may not happen until you're long gone.
2. It's unnecessary for performance unless you have many millions of rows in your product table. Lookups on indexed `varchar()` columns are almost as fast as lookups on integer columns.
3. It's a programming hassle.
4. It's a maintenance hassle long after your programming is done.
5. MySQL (and other database systems) are built for quick SELECT lookups on various kinds of data. Thousands of programmer years (truly!) have gone into making this kind of thing fast. If you think you need to improve on those programmers with a trivial optimization, with respect you're wrong. Certainly in this case.

> Will this be a scalable solution once traffic increases?

Yes, it will. But so will a lookup on your product name.

> Will indexing the checksum column help for Select queries?

Yes, you should index any set of columns used in SELECT queries. Indexing is a bit of an art. Check this out https://use-the-index-luke.com Once you've correctly indexed  a table with less than a million rows, `SELECT` statements should be fast and scalable.

If you don't index the table correctly, your queries will be very slow no matter what datatypes you're looking up.

> I read insert statement will take a performance hit.

A trivial hit.  A few milliseconds per insert, at most.

> Is storing the checksum value as a binary better?

You'll save tens of microseconds on each SELECT if you use binary. Tens of microseconds do not matter.

> Consider the additional task of converting the checksum to binary before every request.

The only thing that counts here is your programming and maintenance time.

Keep your system simple. Don't borrow trouble, especially imagined trouble about the difference between searches on different kinds of data types.